# INSERT values from resultset and TextField in the same table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert, resultset

I am trying to get **matricule** of every item on the JList and the **stage_ID** from a JTextField and insert them in the table **employé_stage** that contains only two columns **stage_ID** and **matricule** as foreign keys  respectively referencing the tables **stage** and **employés**. I want all the records from JList to be inserted in the table **employé_stage** with the same **stage_ID** I'm using this code that returns  **can not add or update child row: foreign constraint fails**

```
private void addstageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
 try{
    for (int i = 0; i < stagelist.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
        String item = stagelist.getModel().getElementAt(i).toString();
        String[] items =item.split("  ");
        if(items.length >= 2){

            String sql ="INSERT INTO stage (nature,datedebs,datefs,durée_S,commentaire,stage_ID) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)  ";    
            String sql2="INSERT INTO employé_stage (matricule) Select  matricule from employés  where nom='"+items[0]+"' and prénom='"+items[1]+"' ";  
            String sql3="INSERT INTO employé_stage  (stage_ID) select  LAST(stage_ID)from stage  ";

            ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ps3 = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 

            ps.setString(6,stageID.getText());


            ps.execute();
            ps2.execute();
            ps3.execute();
        }
    }   

    } catch(Exception ev){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ev);
    }  
    miseajour_tab();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error message (I'm missing `key` after `foreign`), and your `CREATE TABLE` please? WIthout that, I can only guess that `ps3` is forgetting to add a value for the NOT NULL `matricule` column in `employee_stage`..

Comment: Are you expecting `sql2` and `sql3` to create one record or two?

Comment: @schtever  one record

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the foreign key exception because `sql2` and `sql3` are inserting one record each, and the foreign key constraints require that both fields be populated in each record.

You must merge these two into one insert statement like:

```
String sqlboth="INSERT INTO employé_stage (stage_id, matricule) " +
   "( " +
   " select LAST(s.stage_ID), e.matricule from stage s, employés e " +
   " where e.nom='"+items[0]+"' and e.prénom='"+items[1]+"'" +
   ")";
```

Further, you should use placeholders in the insert so you are not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

```
String sqlboth="INSERT INTO employé_stage (stage_id, matricule) " +
   "( " +
   " select LAST(s.stage_ID), e.matricule from stage s, employés e " +
   " where e.nom=? and e.prénom=?" +
   ")";
PreparedStatement psboth = conn.prepareStatement(sqlboth);
psboth.setString(1, items[0]);
psboth.setString(2, items[1]);
psboth.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: this query returnes an Sql Exception : `Subquery returns more than 1 row`  is it because there are multiple row insertion ?

Comment: It might be because your `select matricule ...` might be returning more than one row.  Are there duplicate names in the `employés` table?

Comment: the list contains many records so it's obvious that there is gonna be many insertions but there is no duplicate. i want to insert all `matricule ` of all employees with the same stage_ID.

Comment: `matricule|stage_ID`                                                                                                         (52             |          1  )                                                                                                       (63              |     1)(70 | 1) (80 | 1) .......

Answer (score 0):

i tried with this piece of code, it works but it only inserts the first record of th JList  :

```
  private void addstageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   try{
    for (int i = 0; i < stagelist.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
        String item = stagelist.getModel().getElementAt(i).toString();
        String[] items =item.split("  ");
        if(items.length >= 2){


   String sql2="INSERT INTO employé_stage (stage_id, matricule) " +
                "VALUES ( " +
                " ?, " +
             " (Select matricule from employés where nom='"+items[0]+"' and prénom='"+items[1]+"')" +
               ")";

        ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        ps2.setString(1,stageID.getText());
        ps.execute();
        ps2.execute();

        }}   

    } catch(Exception ev){

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ev);
   }  
    miseajour_tab(); 
    }
```